# Recursive function not working as expected

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to write the code for recursive function which prints every power of 2 from 1 to N, N is the argument of power function.

```
Function : int powers(n)
```

Currently I wrote this code:

```
int powers(int n)  //here n=128 
{        
    if(n==2)
    {
        System.out.print(n);
    }        
    else if (n>2)  
    { 
        System.out.print(n +", ");   
        return powers(n/2); 
    } 
    System.out.println("");
    return 0;
}
```

Output : 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2

Expected : 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128

Comment: What happens if you call `powers(N/2)` (you don't need to return it) _before_ printing out `N`, in the `else if` block?

Comment: I am trying to print 2^1 = 2  -  2^7=128 that's why trying to do return powers(N/2).

Comment: But the only thing your method ever returns is 0, so it's not the `return` that matters, it's the order that you print stuff.  You're printing the current `N` _before_ everything else, but you've implied that you want to print it _after_.

Comment: so how we can reverse this order? as we can get N/2 = 64 and so on.

Comment: By doing what I suggested in my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

As the purpose of your function is printing the powers of 2, you do not need to return the value. Hence, you can rewrite your function as the following:

```
int powers(int N)  //here N=128 
{
    if(N==2){
        System.out.print(N + ", ");
    }
    else if (N >2)  
    {
        powers(N/2); 
        System.out.print(N + ", ");   
    } 
    System.out.println("");
    return 0;
}
```

Also to handle the last extra comma you can return the previous step string and print outside the function.

```
String powers(int N)  //here N=128 
{
    if(N==2){
        return (N + "");
    }
    String prev = powers(N/2); 
    return (prev + ", " + N);   
}
```

Comment: function must return integer

Answer (score 1):

Why are we making the assumption that the input N is already a power of 2? Besides, 2 ^ 0 = 1, should that be in the result as well?

```
public int power(int num) {
    if (num <= 0)
        return -1;

    else if (num <= 1) {
        System.out.print(1);
        return 1;

    } else if (num <= 2) {
        System.out.print(1 + ", " + 2);
        return 2;

    } else {
        int result = 2 * power(num / 2);
        System.out.print(", " + result);
        return result;

    }
}
```

This works even if you give 131 as the input.

Comment: The input could also be negative, you should probably make your first `if` be `<=`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a more elegant way to achieve this. Improvements are supposed to be:

1. Use bit shifting when possible to gain some
   performance.
2. Fix comma placement for all cases of input N
3. More elegant looking code

```js
int powers(int N) //here N=128 
{
  if (N < 2) return 0;
  powers(N >> 1); // Right shifting achieves division by 2 but a lot faster.
  if (N > 3) System.out.print(", "); // Fixing comma placement for all cases of N.
  System.out.print(N);
  return 0;
}
```